# I am trying to build a vertical mousewheel control swiper in react.js but it is not working?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to create a mouse wheel control vertical swiper with react-id-swiper in using react.js but its not working no error no styling just showing the text that is placed in the div. any one can help with athentic solution.

I simply write this code and include css from library.

```
import React from "react";
import Swiper from "react-id-swiper";
import "react-id-swiper/lib/styles/scss/swiper.scss";

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const params = {
      container: ".container",
      pagination: ".swiper-pagination",
      paginationClickable: true,
      direction: "vertical"
    };
    return (
      <Swiper {...params}>
        <div>Slide 1</div>
        <div>Slide 2</div>
        <div>Slide 3</div>
        <div>Slide 4</div>
        <div>Slide 5</div>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to enable the mouse wheel events within your options as described in the Swiper [docs](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#mousewheel):

```
const params = {
  container: ".container",
  pagination: ".swiper-pagination",
  paginationClickable: true,
  direction: "vertical",
  mousewheel: true, // https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#mousewheel
};

return (
  <Swiper {...params}>
    <div>Slide 1</div>
    <div>Slide 2</div>
    <div>Slide 3</div>
    <div>Slide 4</div>
    <div>Slide 5</div>
  </Swiper>
);
```

Comment: can you please show me the code how to set the events for this #Mousewheel control swiper.@wiesson

Comment: Last line in the params object in my example!

Comment: Did it work for you? If yes, I'm happy if you accept my answer!

Comment: I have a querry,

Comment: in react app bootstrap is not working (error module not found )

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Sounds like a different problem, create a new question and describe what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I was able to solve it by doing this:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore, { Keyboard, Mousewheel } from "swiper/core";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

// import required modules
// import { Pagination } from "swiper";

SwiperCore.use([Keyboard, Mousewheel]);

export default function Pages() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView="1"
        mousewheel={true}
        keyboard={{ enabled: true, onlyInViewport: false }}
        direction="vertical"
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        height={window.innerHeight}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```